# Imprimir en el documento

Tags: javascript, dom, condiciones

Hola  buenas tardes ya  imprime la palabra que se ingresa en consola  pero ¿cómo puedo hacer que se imprima en el documento? Agradecería su ayuda y explicación, estoy iniciando

```
var palabra = prompt( "Ingrese una palabra por cada letra del Abecedario")

// crear un nuevo div
var elemento =document.createElement("div");

var newContent = document.createTextNode(palabra);
// añade al div el texto creado  en el div
elemento.appendChild(newContent); 

console.log(newContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas agregar el `div` que creaste al `body` del documento asi:

```js
var palabra = prompt( "Ingrese una palabra por cada letra del Abecedario")

// crear un nuevo div
var elemento =document.createElement("div");

var newContent = document.createTextNode(palabra);
// añade al div el texto creado  en el div
elemento.appendChild(newContent); 
document.body.appendChild(elemento);

console.log(newContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción sería... (más sencilla)

```js
alerta = prompt('Ingrese una palabra por cada letra del Abecedario');

caja = document.body.textContent = alerta;
```

1. Almacenas en una variable la función `prompt()`
2. Almacenas en una variable la etiqueta HTML
3. La variable que tiene la etiqueta HTML, le pasas la propiedad `textContent`
4. Finalmente, a la propiedad `textContent` le pasas la variable que tiene el `prompt()`

[¿Qué es textContent?](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

[¿Qué es el DOM?](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)